# Как сделать так, чтобы вместо текста заголовков вырезался сам li?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо только лишь текста заголовков вырезался сам `li`?
То есть, чтобы следуя скрипту вырезалось второе слово, а также все то, что внутри `<li>`, включая изображение.

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('.productdetails');
[].forEach.call(ul, (item) => {
    const data = [...item.children].reduce((acc, n) => {
    let t = n.innerText.indexOf(' ') != -1 ? n.innerText.split(' ')[1] : n.innerText;
    let k = t[0].toLowerCase();
    (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(t);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const html = Object
    .entries(data)
    .map(([ k, v ]) => `<div class="hua-rotate">${k}</div><ul class="${k}-litter">${v.join('')}</ul></div>`)
    .join('');

  item.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
  item.remove();
});
```

```html
<ul class="productdetails">
 <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Acer</a></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Samsung</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: innerHTML вместо innerText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь при переборе добавляется в массив `data` не просто текст, а обновленный outerHTML с изменённым innerText.

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('.productdetails');
[].forEach.call(ul, item => {
  const data = [...item.children].reduce((acc, n) => {
    let t = n.innerText.indexOf(' ') + 1 ? n.innerText.split(' ')[1] : n.innerText;
    let k = t[0].toLowerCase();
    (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(n.outerHTML.replace(n.innerText, t));
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const html = Object
    .entries(data)
    .map(([k, v]) => `<div><div class="hua-rotate">${k}</div><ul class="${k}-litter">${v.join('')}</ul></div>`)
    .join('');

  item.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
  item.remove();
});
```

```html
<ul class="productdetails">
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Acer</a></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Xiaomi</a></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyIW.jpg?s=48&g=1"><a>Заголовок Samsung</a></li>
</ul>
```